# How to add data label in pie chart and how to set frame/position for the legend screen of pieChart using core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

I have implemented a pie chart on iPhone application by following the [Rayenderlich CORE PLOT tutorial for PIE CHART](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1

Here i have some issues,

I need to **add another data label (Name of project) on the graph**,

I tried with implementing another method like

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

in CorePlot.h (i found only once in the application) and method definition in my viewcontroller class,

but extra datalabel doesn't displayed yet.

And i need to **move the legend table bellow the graph instead of beside the graph**
i tried with frame and legendDisplacement but no result found

Answer (score 2):

Data labels are tied to the plot data, one for each slice in a pie chart. In your example image, "Weekly Report" would be the graph `title`.

```
graph.title = @"Weekly Report";
CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
textStyle.color                = [CPTColor whiteColor];
textStyle.fontName             = @"Helvetica-Bold";
textStyle.fontSize             = 12.0;
graph.titleTextStyle           = textStyle;
graph.titleDisplacement        = 5.0;
graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
```

You can move the legend with the `legendAnchor` property:

```
graph.legendAnchor = CPTRectAnchorBottom;
```

Similar to the `titleDisplacement`, the `legendDisplacement` sets the margin between the legend and its anchor point on the graph.

Comment: yes this is the right way to move the legend, but tits frame stick to a particular postion for each legendAnchor. causes it overlaps the grap

Comment: i want to move the legend entirly bootom 10 pixels fro the graph